# How to extract a number from an existing file using Tokenizer (java)

Tags: java, integer, tokenize, readfile, stringtokenizer

I have this piece of code to extract lines from an existing file using Tokenizer:

```
String line = "";
StringTokenizer inLine;
```

However, I also need to extract integers. How to I extract integers using Tokenizer?